# how can I disable manually switching frames in java

Tags: java

I am quite new to basic software developing and I am creating a bus ticket reservation software using JDK 8 and Eclipse(Kepler) as my IDE. I have almost completed Admin module except for a proper log in session. I have a problem which I beg your pardon can't quite explain.

[image: Image: admin and user log in forms]

In the main form, there are two buttons, one takes you to admin login form and the other to user log in form. While in admin form, the main form runs in the background. Now, if I click anywhere on that form, the admin form gets hidden and in fact all other options in the main form are operational. So, I can actually access user log in form as well. Similarly, after logging in as admin, in the admin options form, I can not only say search for a bus route but simultaneously do other things as well.

Admin forms running simultaneously:

[image: Image: admin forms running simultaneously]

So, I thought of two ways to deal with this. One, prevent background forms from being accessed(clicking anywhere on that form won't hide the current one) and two, disable background forms. But I have no idea how to do either. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Edit: In simpler words, say I am presently accessing admin log in form, so I cannot simultaneously access any other form like user log in form.

Comment: I suggest you add pictures (or links to pictures if you can't add inline pictures to your situation, a moderator will edit the question for you) and demonstrative diagrams to what you want to achieve. If you don't know how exactly to achieve something perhaps add some high level pseudo code to get the concept across. I'm marking the question as "unclear of what you are asking" until this has been cleaned up.

Comment: Hi, how can I add pictures?

Comment: You should be able to embed an inline image by pressing the "Image" icon next to the curly braces at the top of the edit window. Failing an inline image, paste it as a hyperlink instead, a moderator will correct this for you. If I remember correctly, new users are allowed a max of 2 hyperlinks, so choose carefully.

Comment: I am unable to post images, getting an error message about requiring at least 10 reputation points to post images

Comment: Upload them to an external image hosting site, and then link into the post via hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks :) I have edited my question to make my problem more clear. Just don't know the proper title yet :(

Comment: `I am presently accessing admin log in form, so I cannot simultaneously access any other form like user log in form` - and you have been given the answer. Use a modal JDialog.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I thought of two ways to deal with this. One, prevent background forms from being accessed(clicking anywhere on that form won't hide the current one) and two, disable background forms. But I have no idea how to do either.

In general, an application should only have a single `JFrame`.

If you need child windows then you should use a `modal JDialog`. A modal dialog will prevent the user from clicking on the frame until the dialog is closed.

You create a `JDialog` the same way you create a `JFrame`. However you do need to specify the JFrame as the owner of the dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this stage I cannot code that. To be more simpler, while I am accessing one form(say admin log in form), I cannot access any other form(like user log in form). How can I do that?

Comment: @RohanBanerjee,  `Unfortunately, at this stage I cannot code that.` of course you can. There is no reason you can't and this is the proper solution. All you need to do is change JFrame to JDialog. Any other solution would be rewriting Swing event code.